# Router getting several port scans and DOS a minute from foreign IPs. Should I be worried?

Tags: router, ddos, network-scanners

**What Happened:**

I was looking at the logs in my router and saw that suddenly I started getting warnings about "port scan attacks" and "DDOS attempts" every few seconds from my system logs. I thought this was strange, so I started looking more closely. I found:

- Most were foreign IPs (non US)
- They were all different
- Most were identified as problematic:

[image: bad news]

Worse, I noticed that these were coming in every few seconds. :(

**What I tried / read:**

First off, I'm not a security expert so forgive me if this sounds stupid.

- I unplugged my router for 6 hours.
- I read this could potentially be a result of outdated firmware, so I went all out and swapped it out with a brand new router.

I checked, and I'm still getting whacked like every second. I know there's the basic "noise of the internet" but this seems pretty targeted.

**Question:**
Is there anything I can do to make this stop? I tried calling my crap ISP and they basically said "We can't change your IP."

All firewall stuff on the router is by default.

Comment: Somebody scanning your system is not a result of some outdated firmware, it is simply the result of something connected to the internet,. There is nothing you can do to stop this scanning, you can only move it away from your router like with a firewall in front of it etc. As long as you router is not vulnerable (this is were the outdated firmware comes in) such scanning itself does not do actual harm. As for your router claiming DDoS or port scan "attacks" - this is often exaggerated.

Comment: We have a phrase here: "Welcome to the Internet". Every IP-connected device experiences the same thing. This is the "background radiation" of the Internet. No need to worry about its existence. Make sure you have basic security enabled on Internet-facing devices.